# How can I replace a word all the files within a folder in Vim?

Tags: vim

I know that by typing the following: :%s/iwanthis/replacedbythis/g will change all the matching words of the file. How can I do the same for all the files within a folder?

(actually replacing a lot of words like this: padding-bottom:5px;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open Vim with all the files loaded into buffers, and do the replace on all buffers at once with bufdo:

```
% vim *
... when vim has loaded:
:bufdo %s/iwanthis/replacedbythis/g | w
```

The `| w` will write each file back to disk.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [greplace.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1813) that can give you a buffer include all lines matching a given regex across multiple files, then you can modify things in the buffer, and then call another greplace command to make all the changes updated to all these files.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be helpful for those who work without vim

```
find /your_path/to/folder -type f -exec sed -i 's/text_to_be_replaced/new_text/g' {} \;
```

This code replaces all the occurrences of the text in the specified path (/your_path/to/folder). Thought it might be helpful for someone.