# Can "with" be used as an identifier in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I am working on adapting a third-party Python package intended for Python 2.7 (it is asserted) to work with Python 2.6, which, though obsolete, remains the standard Python on many of the machines in my purview.

I have been using the `compileall` module to help me identify compatibility issues, and I have in fact turned up very few.  Only one of those has proven very resistant: the code provided to me uses "with" as an identifier in several places, both as a keyword argument

```
newitems.append(Data(item[:, Numeric.NewAxis], with='lines'))
```

and as an attribute name

```
self.with = keyw['with']
```

.  The byte-compiler barfs on those uses of "with", as it seems it should, given that "with" has been a keyword since Python 2.6.

Inasmuch as the module in question bears an apparent latest revision date in early 2010, and as it has a pedigree dating from much earlier, I'm inclined to think that this module never worked in Python 2.7 (as was claimed) nor even in Python 2.6.  Is there any other plausible conclusion?  Is there any sensible way forward other than replacing "with" with a different identifier in the offending contexts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot. `with` is listed as a reserved word, also known as a keyword, in Python. From the [Python 2.7 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords):

> The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of the language, and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers.

The same is said in the [Python 2.6 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) and even the [Python 2.5 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html). This means that the module did not work, and most likely the only solution would be to change the `with`s to another word. If you are using Vim, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657621/how-can-i-replace-a-word-all-the-files-within-a-folder-in-vim) might help make it an easier task.

---

Trying to use `with` in your Python code will result in a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

```
>>> with = True
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    with = True
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for `bufdo`.  I'm a longtime `vim` user, but that one is new to me.